# Colloquially, how is the verb for writing on LaTeX called?

Tags: spelling, mathematics

I've heard

> getext (with the *x* sounding as [ç])

as participle (whereas, maybe, I should write *geTeXt*). So, there is, at least colloquially, a verb for typing a document in [*LaTeX*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX).

- texen? (ich texe, du texst, er text, usw.) And because the *x* after vowel would give problems (doesn't it?), how would it be pronounced?

Comment: +1 from someone who _always_ pronounces "LaTeX" as [lateks] on purpose, just to mess with those LaTeX-users who are offended by this.

Comment: Konjugiert wie *blechen*.

Comment: Ich würde zu `In LaTeX setzen/schreiben/verfassen` usw. benutzen, um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden. Man tesafilmt auch nicht Buchseiten oder tempot seine Nase, schon seit Jahrzehnten nicht, und ist glücklich. :)

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: Ich schlafe auf einer Latex-Matraze und laTeXe. :-)

Comment: Ich würde nicht schreiben "du textst", sondern "du texst". Im übrigen ist das nicht dasselbe wie bei Tempo oder Tesafilm, denn diese sind eine Marke unter vielen, während es zu TeX KEINE ALTERNATIVE gibt :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that is the verb, *texen* or *TeXen*.

> Ich texe meine Doktorarbeit.

Note that pronunciation may vary. Bavarians sometimes lean towards /x/ for the *x*. Those who are proud of their knowledge of classical Greek will use /k/. But /ç/ is most common across Germany.

Since the pronunciation of the *x* is taken from what Knuth *et al.* originally wanted for *TeX*, it is the same across all persons, numeri and tenses. One could probably write *techen* instead, but that would diverge from the spelling *TeX.*

Comment: So even in this first person, where *x* is before another vowel, *ich texe*, would it be [ˈtɛçɛ], [ˈtɛkɛ] ? I'd like to say it is [ˈtɛksɛ], but I don't know if that is even understandable and not confuesd with *SMS-en*. Would it make sense if I conserve the [ç] only if *x* is not before a vowel?

Comment: @c.p. Yeah, *texe* is /'tɛçə/, /'tɛxə/ or rarely /'tɛkə/. Never /'tɛksə/, unless you want to look bad in the company of TeXers. (Note the final shwa, however.)